# Did ramming tank battle tactics occur in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, tactics, tanks

In one of his War thunder (a realistic tank battle simulator) videos, Oxide used a small, quick tank with a high armor penetration  weaponry, and proceeded to ambush and flank German tanks from alleys, then essentially destroyed them from point-blank range, while the tanks weren't able to do anything, because the target was too close.

[image]

["It's not about size, it's how you use it."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBhVJ6kInRM&t=111s)

**Did such tactics occur in WW2? If yes, the how successful were they against trained tank crews**

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider War Thunder a realistic simulator by any stretch of the imagination. More realistic than World of Tanks? Sure, but that's setting the bar very, very low. In real life, tanks mostly operated in large formations and with combined arms support. They simply didn't wander in to confined ambush areas like this: the ones that did were quickly destroyed by. AT guns and infantry.

Comment: @PhillS Well, I expected that, albeit the trained tank crew specification.

Comment: @PhillS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcMHqUC9YvM

Comment: In the body of the question, does "high armor penetration" refer to the ramming ability of the smaller tank or its weaponry?

Comment: @SteveBird Weaponry.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted In order for this to be a valid tactic in the real world, the question has to be; Did a small, quick tank with a high armor penetration weaponry actually exist? I suspect not. In the pictured example, the small tank would have a better chance by creating a "mobility kill" by ramming and crippling the Tiger tank's tracks/suspension

Comment: @SteveBird I just looked it up, the tank's armor penetration was 108mm from 10 meters, at least based on the screenshot.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted: Which would mean it would have a hard time penetrating the 80mm side armor of the Tiger at any kind of angle. And if he rotates the turret to the right to get a nice 90 deg. angle, he'll ram the gun barrel into the Tiger's side, disabling his gun... the better tactic would be to give some support to the infantry, and have *them* take out the enemy tank.

Comment: @DevSolar Yep, I noticed that bug. Perhaps, if we can saw it off...

Comment: ...significantly reducing the muzzle velocity, and hence the penetration...

Comment: Besides, real-world tanks don't have hit point bars. One good hit is usually enough for a battlefield kill, and you can do *that* from a concealed, stationary ambush position much better than by driving up to the enemy and "facehugging" them (as I said before, leaving you exposed, vulnerable, and with a bit of bad luck, immobilized by impact or secondary explosion).

Comment: @DevSolar In War Thunder, it completely depends on the gameplay mode (arcade, realistic, simulation) and in the video, you could see each shots effect on the tank, in the upper-right corner.

Answer (score 3):

The most lethal enemy of the tank was not another tank.

By percentage, of 1305 WWII tank losses by the British, these were due to:

- 24.4% SPG
- 22.7% AT gun
- 22.1% mines
- 14.5% tank
- 14.2% Bazooka (Panzerfaust, Panzerschreck)
- 2.1% other

While the computer game "tactic" you describe might *or might not* work against a single enemy tank, it doesn't remove the other dangers to your tank in a *real* battle, to the contrary.

Most importantly (as Santiago already pointed out), fighting in a city *very much increases* the threat of AT guns and infantry action (mines, Panzerfaust) due to the close quarters and quite limited vision from within a tank. The chances of two tank units engaging each other in city streets are quite low to begin with.

And your "tactic" would only work against a single Tiger (or similarily large tank), without backup or supporting infantry. Also, actually *ramming* an enemy tank would very likely result in your (lighter) tank being immobilized, not to mention injury of the crew. Also note that the gun barrel of the computer tank in your picture is dangerously close to being rendered inoperative due to smashing into the Tiger's side...

Could it work? Perhaps.

Would it make for a tactic worth "teaching", or "employing" to any significant extend? I don't think so.

Comment: Sources for your data?

Answer (score 0):

In WWII usually tanks avoided closed spaces (woods, cities, etc.), and as a defensive weapon is quite more effective an assault gun (a tank chassis with a gun, but without a mobile turret) or later on the bazooka and the panzerfaust for infantry.
In the case that a tank that you describe, the tank does not need so close to its target, because is too risky. Besides, the penetration of the gun does not increase so drastically when you are so close to the target (10% of penetration loss for every 500 meters).

Seldom times that kind of tactics were used, the most known case is the [Battle_of_Prokhorovka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Prokhorovka), were so many tanks were in the same place at the same time that some Russian tanks tried to get as close as possible during the engagement. In the case of this battle the tactic was successful, because German tanks lost their gun superiority when soviets approached too close.

Comment: Weren't there city tank battles in Stalingrad? Or have I been playing too much Battlefield?

Comment: @T.E.D. And how about 1956, those T-34s have got a bit fried over in Budapest.

Comment: @T.E.D.: There have been tank battles in *Cologne*. [Filmed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBI9d0-IfEM), even. But generally, any tank general would avoid cities.

Answer (score 0):

There were some reports of ramming enemy tanks, but it was never a trained tactic, instead being an act of desperation. Slamming a several ton metal box on treads into another box is likely to result in both being disabled, and generally you want to avoid 1-1 trades of equipment like that.

In terms of getting in too close for the enemy to hit you, Oxide here is helped by the fact he is in a T-50 (basically a baby T-34). The T-34 (the most common Russian tank) is ~8ft tall, while the Tiger I is ~10. He is also helped by the clipping of the gun barrels. He can stick the gun through the enemy tank with no problem. RL physics do not work that way.

On a slightly different note, those (in-game) Tiger's would probably have done better if they just tried to crush the T-50. WT physics can have some interesting effects.

Comment: Oxide rammed them in the sides, but yeah, there were a few interesting things.

Comment: He never rams them with enough force to break either's tracks or knock out their drivers (since being immobilized will likely be the end for the T-50). The Tiger can pivot in place, and should have enough mass to move the T-50 along with it. It would require quick thinking on the Tiger Drivers part, which most WT Tiger Drivers seemed to lack back when I was playing.

Comment: Source for your reports of ramming tanks? The rest, debating game physics mechanics, is off topic in a History forum.